# "\xCB" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 in Amazon Code Deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, aws-code-deploy

I get this error after creating a new instance in an autoscale group and trying to deploy. I also get this error if I create a new instance (not part of autoscale group) and deploy to it.

If I log into this newly created instance, and restart the code deploy agent, and try deploying again, it succeeds. It will now succeed every time.

If I create an image of this instance at this point, and use this image as base for a new auto-scale group, the deploy fails again.

Since I cannot restart the agent during the auto-scale setup, auto-scaling always fails.

Does anybody have any ideas on how to fix this?

I use AWS code pipeline to pull from GitHub. there are no UTF8 issues in the repo. I confirmed line endings are correct too. I converted all non-UTF8 text files to UTF8 to prove this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a recent fix for Ruby encoding issue:

https://github.com/aws/aws-codedeploy-agent/commit/c2f6489a8429c5f09470fa8e354c5406ec4a4d6a.

For this error to happen, it is likely that you have foreign characters as file names that will be deployed onto instances.

Answer (score 0):

Check the format of the appspec.yml file.  You very likely have an encoding/line end problem there.

Comment: I confirmed appspec.yml. All UTF-8 and no weirdness there.

Comment: In what log are you getting the message? Can you post the complete error message?